# How do I make a linked list iterable in javascript using symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to make my singly linked-list iterable in javascript, I tried the commented piece of code but keep getting undefined.
Im learning about javascript linked-list and iteration and trying to iterate through the list and get the sum of each of the numbers in the list.
Ive checked here and tried the solutions but none of them are working :(

```
// User defined class node
class Node {
    // constructor
    constructor(data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }
    add(data){
        let node = new Node(data);
        let current;
        if(this.head === null){
            this.head = node;
        } else{
            current = this.head;
            while(current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }   
            current.next = node;
        }
        this.size++
    }

    // [Symbol.iterator]() {
  //   let current = this.head;
  //   return {
  //     next: () => {
  //       if (!current) return { done: true };
  //       const { data, next } = current;
  //       current = next;
  //       return { data, done: false };
  //     },
  //   };
  // }

    log(){
        let current = this.head;
        let str = "";
        while (current) {
            str += current.data + ", ";
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (str !== "") {
            console.log(str);
        } else{
            console.log("List Is Empty");
        }
    }
}

let sum = 0;
for(const n of ll) {
    console.log(n);
    sum += n;
}

console.log(sum);
// "25"

ll.log();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol) stipulates:

> The `next()` method must always return an object with appropriate properties including `done` and `value`.

But in your code the returned object does not have a `value` property (but a `data` property). So do:

```
return { value: data, done: false };
```

However, it seems more natural to define `Symbol.iterator` as a generator:

```
* [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let current = this.head;
    while (current) {
        yield current.data;
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Tried both and they worked, Ill use the generator.
Really appreciate :)